# Downloading blobs from blobstore in GAE without using class handlers

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I want to ask if I can download files from the blobstore in google app engine (zip files especially) without using the handlers(class handlers),I mean serve files directly without downloadhandler class usage.

Have any idea??

Comment: Why don't you want to write a handler? It's all of 5 lines to serve a blob, given its ID, and not much more to do some sort of path mapping.

Comment: the blobstore documentation shows the usage of BlobstoreDownloadHandler from webapp2. Are you asking how to do it in another framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only can only download images without using your own handlers.
Serving from this "get_serving_url" (Image API) does not incur any CPU or dynamic serving load, only bandwidth.

Comment: i mean without using **class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):**,i understood from your answer that i can't serve any other file,i created zip file on the blobstore but i can't serve it,have any idea?Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the files API to put your zip file in [Google Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/) and then serve it from there rather than from your App Engine app. Otherwise, you have to go via the send_blob mechanism provided by the DownloadHandler.

Comment: :i'm already useing blobstorage and the zip folder created successfuly, but the problem when serving it.

Comment: what is the problem serving it?

Comment: @Nick Johnson:i know that it's simple to serving using download handler,but i can't pass the BlobInfo to this handler,and when i try to execute just this handler,i have this problem:((Status: 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0))Have any idea about this problem?Thanks.